# How to convert an HTML string to an escaped one?

Tags: c#, string, controller

I have a function that reads an HTML file and returns the value as a string, however, the string output contains a backslash whenever there are quotes in the HTML attributes.

Function:

```
public string Get(string page)
{
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(page);
    
    var content = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html");

    return content;
}
```

Output:

```
<head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
   <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
   <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">
   <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"url\"
</head>
```

Desired Output:

```
<head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="url"
</head>
```

Is there a way to remove the backslashes that appear in the attributes tags?
I have tried using replace but it doesn't work, I have also tried HttpUtility.HtmlDecode but both don't seem to work

Comment: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)  You need to encode not decode.

Comment: I have also tried HtmlEncode, it still returns the backslash in the output

Comment: How are you viewing this result? If in the debugger that doesn't mean anything, it's just a display artifact

Comment: A backslash does  not need to be escaped.

Comment: I know it doesn't, but when trying to render the ouptut as HTML, none of the attribute values could be read